# Looking for words with a similar meaning to Pocket-veto

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I am currently looking for words that mean, "To nullify an event or call, by ignoring the event or call, until the event or call has passed". I know Pocket-veto fits the bill (I apologize in advance for this pun), however I'm looking for a more informal word, as I can best describe it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In US English, you can use *to table*

> Postpone consideration of:
>
> *I'd like the issue to be tabled for the next few months*

([Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/table))

By tabling a bill, either literally or figuratively, the president effectively pocket  vetoes it if it's less than ten days before Congress adjourns.

Comment: Be aware, in Australian English (not sure about British) this means the exact opposite, to table an issue means to discuss it right now. I assume the interpretation stems from putting sth on the table. I learned this the hard way... ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want *very* informal:

[***blow off***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blow--off)

> to ignore, evade, or treat as unimportant ("I mentioned his insulting remark, and he just blew the whole thing off"); to not go to or participate in ("He blew off his first-period class three times that week"); to fail to meet (someone) as planned without alerting the person beforehand ("I waited 20 minutes before I realized my sister had blown me off").

(dictionary.com)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this, which implies that missing the opportunity is not intentional:

> [***miss the boat***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/miss-the-boat) - (informal) to lose an opportunity to do something by being slow to act

If there is full intent, you might just *pass on it*, or *take a pass* on it.

> [***pass on something***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pass-on-something-someone) - to refuse an opportunity

([*Cambridge Dictionary*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/))